# Does PHP create the directory for the error log if it does not exist?

Tags: logging, php

Does PHP create the directory for the error log if it does not exist?

For example, the `error_log` directive is set to `/var/logs/php/errors.log` but the folder `/var/logs/php` does not exist.

Comment: Gooood question, I liked

Comment: Well, create a PHP file and put an error in it. See what happens. Was the folder created? I do not mean to sound patronizing, but this seems like something you can figure out by just trying it out.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: The moment you submitted your comment, all that was already done. It would have only required you to look not only at the question but also at the answer. The "answer your own question" kind posting has been done here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not the case. If the directory for the logfile does not exist, it is not automatically created.

If you log only errors to file, no errors will be logged and no notice about that is given.

Tested with PHP 5.4.13

Comment: @Fluffeh: I dunno if that qualifies as a bug. It might be considered a flaw from some perspective but as this is I/O bound I personally do not think that it should be created. Also this can have serious security implications, before I judge about it I would consult a sysadmin first. It's just I needed to find out and googling didn't went well so I Q&A'ed it here for future reference.